# IE corrupts encoding of the text taken from javascript file served by DFP

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, encoding, google-dfp

There is a problem of how ads get displayed by DFP on IE.
I tracked the problem downt to this issue.

Content of the ad is loaded from the address

```
http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?....
```

The content of the file is similar to the following:

```
window.parent.googletag.impl.pubads.setAdContentsBySlotForAsync([{"/8019203/FBRU_180x150":{"_type_":"html","_expandable_":true,
       "_html_":"текст баннера",
       "_snippet_":true,"_height_":150,"_width_":180,
       "_empty_":false,"_is_afc_":false,
      "_is_psa_":false,"_is_3pas_":true}}]);
```

So the content of the _ html _ is a russian text which gets displayed in IE like a text with corrupted encoding.
[image]

Other browsers display the same content correctly:
[image]

Invoking **setAdContentsBySlotForAsync** with a english text display also correctly in IE.

Fiddler shows that all requests have charset header set to UTF-8. Also adding chartset attributes to all places where script elements get created with value utf-8 do not resolve problem.